# Dispatching A Non-Blocking Fetch Request From Within A Next.js API Route (App Router)

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I am trying to make a fetch request from within an API route from Next.js 13 (App Router). I do not want to block that request, because I am simply dispatching it and then moving on. However, when I do not block the fetch request, it does not fire, but when I put an "await" at the start of the request, it does fire.

I am running a Next.js 13 (App Router) project that is hosted on Vercel.

I have not found anything elsewhere discussing this, so hopefully someone can provide some insight here. Here is my function (please note this is inside an asynchronous POST route):

```
export default async function generateEmbeddingsForPDF(
    workspaceDataSource: WorkspaceFile, 
    supabase: SupabaseClient<Database, 'public'>,
    request: NextRequest
): Promise<boolean>
{
    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .storage.from('workspace-files')
    .download(workspaceDataSource.filePath);

    if (error && !data)
    {
        console.error('ERROR Downloading File::', error);
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        const pdfLoader = new PDFLoader(data);
        const pageContentList = (await pdfLoader.loadAndSplit()).map(page => page.pageContent);
        const chunkSplitSize = 50;

        for (let i = 0; i < pageContentList.length; i += chunkSplitSize)
        {
            try
            {
                const chunks = pageContentList.slice(i, i + chunkSplitSize);
                const url = `${request.nextUrl.origin}/api-v1/workspaces/generate-embeddings/ingestor`;
                console.log('INGESTOR URL::', url);

                // This does not work unless I put an await at the start. 
                axios.post(url, {
                    workspaceFile: workspaceDataSource,
                    textChunks: chunks,
                    totalChunks: pageContentList.length,
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        cookie: request.headers.get('cookie'),
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.error('ERROR WITH EMBEDDINGS DISPATCHER::', error);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error('Error splitting pdf into pages::', error);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To run it, all I have to do is post to /api-v1/workspace/generate-embeddings.

Also this works in my development environment, but not in production, so if there's some weird quirk about Vercel not allowing same-origin fetch requests then please explain it to me :D

The reason why I am doing it this way is because I want to let the user know that the process has begun, returning the original API route as soon as possible. Also, by dividing up the workload into segmented parts, it means that I can avoid a timeout due to the 5 minute function limit I have with Vercel (some PDFs take 10-15 minutes doing it serially).

Comment: If you're hosting the backend serverless, like vercel does, then the server will get torn down if it's not doing any work. That may mean that unfinished requests get cancelled but I'm not sure. Can you give more info what you're trying to do, what you mean by "doesn't work", and how you've verified that it "doesn't work".

Comment: So by doesn't work I mean the the ingestor endpoint never gets called. It's almost like the fetch request is being skipped.

I have verified it does not work because of Vercel's logging. I can see that when I append the "await" call at the start, the api route appears as working in the logs (and the relevant database changes), however without the await there is none of that.

Comment: Ok, so you're verifying by logging something at the ingestor endpoint? And so without await you don't get a single log? My suspicion is the server gets torn down before the request has a chance to fire. You can verify that by waiting 10 seconds before returning `await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1e4))`.

Comment: Yes I can verify it works with the await, but does not without. If it gets torn down before it can actually send out the fetch request, then that would make sense.

I'll give your suggestion a try and then I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: Ok so the block works, thank you so much! You were right in your assumption.

Comment: I didn't mean use that as a solution lol, that was just to verify what's happening

Comment: The solution is to await your requests before returning (preferably in parallel with `Promise.all()`). Then just don't await this endpoint from wherever you are calling it from. I'm not at my desktop so can't type out an example rn.

Comment: I mean it solves the problem I'm facing, but yes you're right it is the most technically correct to use `Promise.all()`. I'll update my response with the solution in a moment.

Comment: Yeah this is a limitation of serverless, you can't send a response and then do work after like you can in serverful. At least Vercel's implentation anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution to this problem was that, as pointed out by Chris Hamilton, the axios/fetch request was being torn down before it could even fire off. I suspect that the latency involved in dispatching the fetch request was greater than the duration of the requests, so I put them into an array of promises and then awaited all of them here. Keep in mind my code does not care about what happens with those promises, simply that all of them have been dispatched.

Here is what I put in before the return, so as to block:

```
try
{
    const pdfLoader = new PDFLoader(data);
    const pageContentList = (await pdfLoader.loadAndSplit()).map(page => page.pageContent);
    const chunkSplitSize = 50;

    const promises: AxiosPromise[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < pageContentList.length; i += chunkSplitSize)
    {
        try
        {
            const chunks = pageContentList.slice(i, i + chunkSplitSize);
            const url = `${request.nextUrl.origin}/api-v1/workspaces/generate-embeddings/ingestor`;
            console.log('INGESTOR URL::', url);

            // This does not work unless I put an await at the start. 
            const embeddingPromise = axios.post(url, {
                workspaceFile: workspaceDataSource,
                textChunks: chunks,
                totalChunks: pageContentList.length,
            }, {
                headers: {
                    cookie: request.headers.get('cookie'),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            });

            promises.push(embeddingPromise);

        }
        catch (error)
        {
            console.error('ERROR WITH EMBEDDINGS DISPATCHER::', error);
        }
    }

    await Promise.all(promises);
}
catch (error)
{
    console.error('Error splitting pdf into pages::', error);
    return false;
}

return true;
```